# Why does webkit view not connect to App Store

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

The following code does not work:

```
override func loadView() {
    self.view = webView

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/economics-a-level/id1300094663?mt=8")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url as URL))
}
```

But if instead I put https://apple.com it does work.

I am using a test device.

So how can I direct a user to my app on the App Store?

Comment: Define "does not work". In what way exactly isn't your URL doing what you expect?

Comment: FYI - you may want to consider using `SKStoreProductViewController` instead of using a web view.

Comment: When I search on the web for this there doesn’t appear to be anything recent or in swift, only objective c.  I use swift.

Comment: Check [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SKStoreProductViewController+%5Bswift%5D) and look at the reference documentation.

Comment: Maddy. What you said was just what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a webview to open the app store, simply do this:

```
let url = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1300094663"
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!)
```

Comment: I know that but I thought if I use a webView I might be able to add constraints so that the web page didn't take up the whole screen and I could therefore return easily to the home page.

Comment: That would certainly break my expectation of what happens when you send me to the App Store - I'd expect to use it normally, download, rate, whatever, and go back either via the top left nav button or the task switcher.

Comment: The trouble is the top left nav button doesn't take me back to the app but to a now empty web page (because there is no page to go back to).

Comment: There should be no web view or web page involved at all.